# Gravitation between a homogeneous ring and a mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, newtonian-gravity

[image: A ring and a point mass.]

I got a problem with describing the gravitational attraction between a homogeneous ring and a point mass.

Let $m$ be the point mass as showed in the picture, lying a $x$-distance away on the $x$-axis which goes straight through the center of the ring $O$ of mass $M$ total. The unit vector $\hat{i}$ points from $m$ to $O$. Because the ring is homogeneous, we introduce the constant linear mass density $\rho$, which is determined by the relationship $ 2 \pi a \rho = M$. Because of reasons of symmetry, the net force on $m$ shall point towards $O$. 
Let the element $dM$ be as showed, which makes an angle $\theta$ with the horizontal. Because the net force is along the unit vector $\hat{i}$, we project the force-component of $dM$ on $\hat{i}$ and have: \begin{align*} d\vec{F} = \frac{GmdM}{r^2} \cos(\theta) \hat{i} \end{align*} with $\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}$. Hence: \begin{align*} d\vec{F} = \frac{GmdMx}{r^3} \hat{i} \end{align*} What should I do now to get the attraction of the total ring? Take the integral or sommation?

Is there another way to do this which includes the constant linear mass density introduced? (Because I haven't used that now).

Answer (score 1):

Technically you should integrate, but because of the problem symmetry this is pretty simple. Note that every $dM$ will produce the same force because they are at the same distance, so

\begin{align*} F= \int dF = \int \frac{Gm}{r^2} \cos\theta dM = \frac{Gm}{r^2} \cos\theta \int dM = \frac{GmM}{r^2} \cos\theta =  \frac{GmM}{x^2} \cos^3\theta  \end{align*}

Comment: I don't understand your last step, where you go to $\cos (\theta)^3$. And why are all the $dM$ at the same distance? If I take one on the left side and the other on the right side, isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Kamil I replaced $r=x/\cos\theta$. And all dM on the ring are at the exact distance r (up, down, left or right, whatever point).